# SDL_RenderSetViewport takes all drawn objects

Tags: c++, c++14, sdl, sdl-2

Im creating an viewport on the superior right corner, where i render an image. but i end up rendering all objects that i draw on that viewport instead of the rest of the screen. in this case i have drawn a triangle.

this is the code:
window

```
Window::Window (const std::string &title, int width, int height): title(title),width(width),height(height){closed=!init();}

bool Window::init(){
  window=SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,width,height,0);
  renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}

void Window::clear() const{
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); 
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,200,255);
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);   
}
```

the draw code:

```
Draw::Draw(int w,int h,int x,int y,int r,int g,int b,int a):w(w),h(h),x(x),y(y),r(r),g(g),b(b),a(a){}

Draw::Draw(int w,int h,int x,int y,const std::string &image):w(w),h(h),x(x),y(y){
   auto surface = IMG_Load(image.c_str());
   texture=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Window::renderer,surface);
   SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}

void Draw::drawline() const{
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Window::renderer,r,g,b,a);
  SDL_RenderDrawLine(Window::renderer,x,y,w,h);
}

void Draw::drawviewport() {
  SDL_Rect viewport ={x,y,w,h};
  SDL_RenderSetViewport(Window::renderer, &viewport );
  SDL_RenderCopy( Window::renderer, texture, NULL, NULL );
  SDL_RenderSetViewport(Window::renderer, NULL );
}
```

main code:

```
Window window("test SDL 1", 1920, 1080);
Draw rs(960,550,960,0,"deposit/sdl.jpg");

Draw linha1(0,400,200,200,255,255,0,0);
Draw linha2(400,400,200,200,255,255,0,0);
Draw linha3(400,400,0,400,255,255,0,0); 

while(!window.isClosed()){

    rs.drawviewport();

    linha1.drawline();
    linha2.drawline();
    linha3.drawline();

    window.clear();
}
```

Comment: You never reset viewport back to fullscreen (`SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, NULL)`). However at this point it is unclear why you need separate viewports at all - what's written in question better be done with single `RenderCopy` with your "viewport" structure as destination rectangle.

Comment: @ keltar i have added that line and it now works. thanks!! I have also edited he first post to add the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by [keltar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744720/keltar):

You never reset viewport back to fullscreen (SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, NULL)). However at this point it is unclear why you need separate viewports at all - what's written in question better be done with single RenderCopy with your "viewport" structure as destination rectangle.